# Remote Triggered Switch for a Water Heater socket

Tags: wiring, switch

I have a  Water Heater ( 3 kW; 220 V; single phase) situated in one bathroom that has plumbing to service two bathrooms.

Currently it is connected to a local wall outlet (15 Amp) in Bathroom-1 with a local switch.

Is there an easy way to provide another remote switch in Bathroom-2 which can also control the Wall Outlet in Bathroom-1? I'm not sure of the operating logic yet; but perhaps a toggle with the last command operational, on or off, irrespective of whether issued locally or remotely. The idea being allowing the heater to be turned on ( or off) from Bathroom-2 as well.

Something like a relay? If the switch in Bathroom-2 can communicate wireless-ly to the Switch in Bathroom-1 that's even nicer. It eliminates the need to add wiring.

Comment: Where in the world are you?

Comment: Also, am I correct in assuming that this water heater is point-of-use/mini-tankless, not a storage/tank-type heater?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: Yes, right. It is point of use. The water heater is located in the bathroom itself & is only piped to two shower heads. And a faucet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing a 3-way switch, which is among the most cheap and common electrical elements you will find.

You can pay up a bit for a 3-way switch with "pilot light" which will illuminate the switch when the circuit is closed (or open, depending on how wired), so that users will know whether toggling the switch will be turning the receptacle on or off.

Given the purpose you describe I would actually run the receptacle off of two single-pole switches wired in parallel so that it is on if *either* bathroom is calling for heat.

And yes, there are plenty of wireless solutions to toggle power at a wall receptacle if you want to spend the money for them instead of hard-wiring a 3-way switch.

Comment: If this had been done correctly from Day-1 a three way switch sounds perfect. But in this case adding a three way would mean a lot of rewiring, right? The wiring is all concealed in the walls. That's why I was thinking in terms of a remote relay. Do you have a link to a wireless solution for this purpose?

Comment: Pulling wires through adjacent walls is very easy, and you're only talking about adding one cable to add the second switch.  For wireless solutions (like a wireless switch/relay) I often browse at SmartHome.com to get an idea of what's currently on the market.  E.g., [here's an X10-compatible 220V 15A outlet switch](http://www.smarthome.com/heavy-duty-220v-15a-appliance-module.html).

Comment: Thank you! This looks like a great site. I will have a look.